# Tell GNU screen where to save the sessions?

Tags: gnu-screen, sockets, session

My GNU screen stores its sessions in the `/tmp` directory.

That means that after a reboot, all sessions are *lost*:

```
$ screen -list 
No Sockets found in /tmp/uscreens/S-dehmann.
```

How can I tell it to store them in a specific directory in my home directory, where they won't be lost so easily?

Comment: What good are the sockets after a reboot? The controlling SCREEN process, and all its children will have been terminated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the manual:

```
The "socket directory" defaults either to $HOME/.screen or simply to
/tmp/screens or preferably to /var/run/screen chosen at  compile-time...
```

By setting the environment variable `SCREENDIR` you can change the default behavior.