# Hibernating/Saving state of a gnu-screen, to resume after reboot?

Tags: linux, hibernate, gnu-screen, bsd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make GNU screen survive reboot](https://superuser.com/questions/341146/make-gnu-screen-survive-reboot)

Is it possible to hibernate or save the current state of a gnu-screen to resume after reboot?

Comment: See the [question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810961/make-gnu-screen-survive-reboot) and [this SU question](http://superuser.com/questions/177955/gnu-screen-sessions-are-dead-after-rebooting-computer-how-to-fix-this) (not exactly a duplicate).